# Select main parent property name of a property name using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "Name 1",
        "color": "green",
        "something_else": {
            "name" : "Name 2"
        }
    },
    "bar": {
        "name": "Name 3",
        "color": "red"
    }
}
```

How to get the proprety name `foo` from `"Name 2"` using jq ?
I tried

```
.[] |select(."name"=="Name 2")
```

And how to get a list `[foo,bar]` (all main parents) from the property name `name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
jq 'path(recurse|select(.name?=="Name 2"))[0]' file.json
```

Comment: Thank you but using -2 you are specifing where the prorety is, but in real life senario it can be anywhere .. if you know what I mean.

Comment: I wasn't clear about that requirement. Does [0] works instead? (for your use case?)

Comment: Oh you're right, was a stupid question, but can u please tell me how to do the same independently from the property `name` value? I tried this but it is wrong `path(recurse|select(.name?==?))[0]` .. I mean the second question in my post

Comment: Ok I found a solution `path(recurse|select(.name? !=""))[0]`.. Many thanks